# How to remove more than 200 stacks at a time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3, aws-ssm

I have 200+ stacks in one account and 30+ stacks in another account. all starts with the name of "test*". so i created the SSM automation document to remove all at once (account by account).

when i ran the document in the account which holds 30+ stacks, it works fine. it cleared everything. but if try the same in 200+ stack account, it lists and removes only few of it. not all at once. if i execute it for the first time, it removes 40+ stacks of that 200+ stacks. the second time, it removes nly 30+. likewise, it kept going and one point of time, its stoppe listing and removing.

could someone please look at my code and help me with the solution.?

```
    import boto3

    def script_handler(events, context):

      client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
        
      response = client.list_stacks(StackStatusFilter=['CREATE_IN_PROGRESS','CREATE_FAILED','CREATE_COMPLETE','ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS','ROLLBACK_FAILED','ROLLBACK_COMPLETE','DELETE_IN_PROGRESS','DELETE_FAILED','UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS','UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS','UPDATE_COMPLETE','UPDATE_FAILED','UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS','UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED','UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS','UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE','REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS','IMPORT_IN_PROGRESS','IMPORT_COMPLETE','IMPORT_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS','IMPORT_ROLLBACK_FAILED','IMPORT_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'])
      for cfn_stack in response['StackSummaries']:
        all_stacks = cfn_stack['StackName']
        
        need_to_delete = events['StackName']
        
        if all_stacks.startswith(need_to_delete):
          stacks_to_be_deleted = cfn_stack['StackName']
          print("deleting {}".format(stacks_to_be_deleted))
          client.delete_stack(StackName=stacks_to_be_deleted)
```

Comment: Boto3 [list_stacks](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation/client/list_stacks.html) is a paginated operation.